# How to pass multiple callback parameters inside a jQuery asynchronous ajax call?

Tags: jquery

I am starting to use some basic ajax calls in jQuery.  The call works well, but I want to pass additional parameters to the callback function in addition to the ajax response.  The additional variables I want to pass are:  map_div, data_name, var_name

It's not clear to me how I can pass those through the callback function (DrawWoldMap).  Anyone know the syntax for that?

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
function OnLoad() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'chart_feeds/parcel/map.php?start='+from_date+'&end='+to_date,
      data: '{}',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: DrawWorldMap
   });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery pass more parameters into callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `DrawWorldMap` with the following snippet:

```
function (response) {
    DrawWorldMap(response, map_div, data_name, var_name);
}
```