# Access Array object in a Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, callback

I can't access data[i] in the callback function.
This is my code:

```
var data = ['HI', 'Hi2'];

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
console.log(data[i]); // Just works fine
//use mysql to query database
mysql.query('some sql stuff', function(err,result){
  console.log(data); // Just works fine
  console.log(data[i]); // Doesn't work
  }
);
}
```

Comment: I think the `i` doesn't exist inside your `mysql.query` return. Try `console.log(i)` instead of `console.log(data[i])`

Comment: thats not what i'm looking for. i want the number i of the data array

Comment: Though probably not relevant to your issue - which I cannot see an obvious solution to - you're likely missing a `var` in front of your iteration variable declaration (i.e., `var i = 0`).

Comment: I said Try `console.log(i)` to check if `i` is working in that part of the code..........

Comment: sry i copied the code very bad. in my code i've tried out with and without `var i=0`

Comment: im sorry. `i` is not correct. i have 2 elements and `i = 2` (0,1,2) it should be 0 + 1, not 2 + 2

Comment: What does the second console.log output? Do you get Hi2 twice?

Comment: I dont think `i` is a global variable.

Comment: function(err,result){
  console.log(data); // Just works fine
  console.log(data[i]); // Doesn't work
  }          this is a callback function that won't be called until the mysql data is returned.  This does not stop your loop, and i will be whatever value it is assigned as in the loop when that function does get called.  Do a search for closures inside a loop.

Comment: yes ryan. the result is twice hi2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978911/closure-inside-a-for-loop-callback-with-loop-variable-as-parameter

Answer (score 0):

By the time your first SQL query finishes the loop is complete and the value of `i` is 1 so I would expect your code to log `hi2` twice. Move your query outside of the for loop.

```
var data = ['HI', 'Hi2'];

for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  console.log(data[i]); // Just works fine
  //use mysql to query database
  logStuff(i);
} 

function logStuff(i) {
  mysql.query('some sql stuff', function(err,result){
    console.log(data); // Just works fine
    console.log(data[i]); // Doesn't work
  });
}
```

Comment: `data.forEach(function(value, index){
 mysql.query('...', function(err, result){ 
  console.log(index, value, err || result);
 });
})`