# Callback to .delay()

Tags: jquery

I have an `$image` that I `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut`, and then `.remove` after `.fadeOut` completes. This is my code:

```
$image
   .fadeIn()
   .fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).remove();
   });
```

I want to add a `.delay` after `.fadeOut`, and `.remove` the `$image` only once `.delay` has completed. I have tried:

```
$image
   .fadeIn()
   .fadeOut()
   .delay(1000, function() {
      $(this).remove();
   });
```

The problem is that `.delay` doest *not* accept a callback function. How can I `.remove` the picture as a callback to `.delay`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method to schedule your own function to run after `delay()` completes:

```
$image.fadeIn()
      .fadeOut()
      .delay(1000)
      .queue(function(next) {
          $(this).remove();
          next();
      });
```

Comment: There is currently no way to add parameters to the queued function, is there?

Comment: @CBenni, indeed there isn't. You can call functions with arbitrary parameters from the queued function, but you cannot specify additional parameters to the queued function itself.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I found a way to achieve what I need however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback  - "The solution is the binding of variables through closure."

Answer (score 5):

You can always do it as:

```
$image
    .fadeIn()
    .fadeOut(function() {
        var self = this; // Not sure if setTimeout
                         // saves the pointer to this
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).remove();
        }, 1000)
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, you can just strap the calls on *after* the delay call, like this:

```
$image
   .fadeIn()
   .fadeOut()
   .delay(1000)
   .remove()
});
```

Such as in the following example from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

The temperament of queued items execution spelled out there also:

> ...the .delay() method allows us to delay
>   the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used
>   with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only
>   subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not
>   delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use
>   the effects queue.

Read the documentation for further information regarding *which* queue you're delaying, if you have troubles with the default `fx` queue you might need to specify one.

Comment: I was sure `.delay` worked only with animation stuff. I mean, wouldn't it remove the `$image` instantly?

Comment: The example only works because `fadeIn()` queues an animation to be run after the delay. `remove()` does not queue anything (it executes synchronously), so the element will be removed from the DOM immediately, without waiting for the animation queue to complete.

Comment: @Honneykeepa You can specify the queue on which the delays occur - it defaults to `fx`.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: I don't think this works. The image gets removed immediately. See http://jsfiddle.net/ntzs4/

Comment: @Randomblue That's because `queue` is queuing the `fx` calls, you'll need to specify your queue.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: I'm a little confused. Could you please provide a working example? Ideally, jsfiddle.

Comment: @Randomblue Here is a working example with an explicit queue, much like Frédéric's implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/ntzs4/1/