# start functions after jquery delay

Tags: jquery, callback, delay

i would animate two elements after a delay called on the parent element.
the HTML could be like this:

```
<div id='daddy'>
 <span id='text'>some text</span><a id='link'>a link</a>
</div>
```

i need something like this to call "function"

```
$("#daddy").fadeIn(300).delay(10000).function()
{
 $("#text").animate({[some stuff]});
 $("#link").animate(
  {
    [some stuff],
    [some other]
  });
}
```

i tried to have a look on .trigger("myPersonalEvent") and creating a customized event, but i think is not the right way to perform what i need...
good idea could be allowing a callback after delay(), but it's not possible

i also appended a fake animation calling a fallback after that, but neither this solution excites me so much..

something better?

Comment: An answer to a similar question is what I found useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915140/callback-to-delay

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) inside of the callback function for `fadeIn`.:

```
$("#daddy").fadeIn(300, function () {   
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $("#text").animate({[some stuff]});
        $("#link").animate(
        {
            [some stuff],
            [some other]
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```