# How do I add more arguments to my function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, node.js-connect

I'm using NodeJS, express, and passport. However I think this question is just about javascript.
In my routes file, I have

```
app.get(  '/users', login_req, user.index);
```

so when the server receives a get request at /users, it will pass `req, res, next` through the login_req function, and login_req will call the user.index function if a user is authorized. I'm wondering if and how I can add more arguments to login_req? My goal is to be able to pass in additional args like `login_req(['admin'],['user1', 'user2'])` to be able to select which users have access to user.index.

Here is my login_req code:

```
exports.login_req = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login')
}
```

I guess, in general, I'm wondering how to attach more arguments to a callback.

Comment: Your syntax is a little off. `login_req({'admin'}, {'user1', 'user2'});` would be closer to what you need.

Comment: Sounds like you need a callback.

Comment: Actually, what? Why would the syntax be like that? {}'s are used for objects like `person={firstname:"John",lastname:"Doe",age:50,eyecolor:"blue"};`, so how would that make sense? I changed the original question to have arrays instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer should work, however I was looking for a more organized solution. Using what I learned from the above answer, I came up with the following.

I learned from [jQuery pass more parameters into callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback) on how to add more parameters into a callback. Here is my code:

```
exports.login_req = function(groups, users) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(groups, users)
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/login')
  };
}
```

and

```
app.get(  '/users', login_req("group1"), user.index);
```

The callback to login_req passes groups = "group1" and users = undefined. login_req returns the anonymous function with args `req, res, next` and `groups, users`, available by closure.  I've printed out groups and users for proof of concept, and it seems to work.

I preferred this method, since now I can have my routes.js file organized like so:

```
app.get(  '/users',          login_req("admins"),     user.index);
app.get(  '/users/new',                               user.new);
app.post( '/users',                                   user.create);
app.get(  '/users/:id',                               user.show);
app.get(  '/users/:id/edit', login_req("admins", "user1"), user.edit);
app.put(  '/users/:id',      login_req("admins", "user1"), user.update);
app.del(  '/users/:id',      login_req("admins", "user1"), user.destroy);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass an anonymous function to `get` and call `login_req` from within that:

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    login_req(req, res, next, something, somethingElse);
}, user.index);
```

Comment: I'd ideally like something more clean, since I have more than 20 of these app.get, app.post, etc. lines. I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback to find a solution, which I will post below.