# jquery ajax post with params

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I need to upload file using JQuery's $ajax function, besides uploading the file, i want be able to tell which folder/directory this filed uploaded to. i tried the following but it won't work:

```
  data = new FormData()
  data.append('csv', fileData)
  $.ajax
    cache: false
    contentType:false
    processData: false
    type: 'POST'
    dataType: 'script'
    url: '/api/upload/'
    params: ['test']   <-- folder/directory i want to upload to
    data: data

    complete: (res) =>
      if not (res.status is 200)
        console.log(res.responseText)
        return false
      else
        return true
```

the api worked fine, but when check the request it always showed the params as empty:

```
params: []
query: {}
```

how can i pass extra parameter to ajax post? thanks

Comment: Try search more, you will find this is helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23797700/1241980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the additional param to the formData

```
data = new FormData()
data.append('csv', fileData)
data.append('path', 'my/path')
```

There is no option called `params` in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)