# How to pass a variable to a listener/handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, projekktor

I'm using projekktor for streaming my videos on browsers. I have many listeners attached on the event `state`.

```
video.addListener('state', listener1);
video.addListener('state', listener2);
video.addListener('state', listener3);
```

Inside the function listener3 and when `state === 'COMPLETED'` I need to remove the listener `listener3`. The thing is that to remove a listener you need the variable video.
Given that listener3 is a callback, **How do I pass the variable video to the function listener3?**

Comment: The answer will completely depend on how and where listener3 is defined relative to the addListener invocation.

Comment: This works like a charm! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback#answer-939206

Answer (score -1):

To remove an event listener in JavaScript use:

Modern browser's:

```
video.removeEventListener('name', fnName);
```

Older ie:

```
video.detachEvent('name', fnName);
```

DOM level 0:

```
video['on' + name] = null;
```

jQuery:

```
video.off('name');
```

Comment: Look at the bold part of the question: "*How do I pass the variable video to the function listener3?*" You've not answered the question.

Comment: First I'm very sorry been a long day and im very tierd must have zoomed past it :) ... And Second i'm pretty sure you could use **listener3(video);**

Comment: `addListener ` takes two parameters: a string and a reference to a function. `addListener( 'state', listener3(video) )` would pass, not the function, but the result of the function. That's not what the OP was looking for.