# Passing a parameter to a function, while keeping the event handler

Tags: javascript, function, events, parameters

this might have been asked, but doing a brief search, I couldn't find an answer.

I am creating a function to handling user events, and I don't know how to pass a parameter into the function, without ruining the event handler.

Here is my code:

```
function keydown(e) {
e = e || window.event;
if (e.keyCode == '38' || e.keycode == '40' || e.keyCode == '37' || e.keyCode == '39')
    e.preventDefault();

switch(e.keyCode){
    case 38: //Up
        console.log('UP');
        break;
    case 40: //Down
        console.log('DOWN');
        break;
    case 37: // Left
        console.log('LEFT');
        break;
    case 39: //Right
        console.log('RIGHT');
        break;
}}
```

I would like something like this:

```
    function keydown(e, myParam) {
        console.log(myParam); // Console logging the second parameter
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == '38' || e.keycode == '40' || e.keyCode == '37' || e.keyCode == '39')
            e.preventDefault();

        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 38: //Up
                console.log('UP');
                break;
            case 40: //Down
                console.log('DOWN');
                break;
            case 37: // Left
                console.log('LEFT');
                break;
            case 39: //Right
                console.log('RIGHT');
                break;
        }
    }
```

Anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a closure:

```
function keydown(param) {
  return function(e) {
    console.log(param)
    ...
  }
}

elem.addEventListener('keydown', keydown(param))
```

Comment: Awesome. Neverthought of returning a function :) Thanks!