# Adding same item too many times to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, select

I am trying to add the same list of names to 10 different select forms in html via javascript.
While this code works, it adds the list of names to each box 10 times. However, if I don't have the q loop, then nothing gets added at all.

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, but I just don't want the same list of names to be added 10 times. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  var names = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
  //window.alert(names[i])
  document.write('<tr>');
  document.write('<td>');
  document.write('Enter name '+ names[i]);
  document.write('</td>');
  document.write('<td>');
  document.write('<select name=' + i + ' id=' + names[i] + '></select>');     
  var textFile = "/names.txt";       
  jQuery.get(textFile, function(textFileData) { 
  var EachName= textFileData.split("\n");
  for (q = 0; q < 10; q++) { 
    var select = document.getElementById(names[q]);
    for (var j = 0, len = EachName.length; j < len; j++) {
       var option = document.createElement('option');
       option.text = option.value = EachName[j];
       select.add(option, 0);
    }
   }
});
document.write('</td>');
document.write('</tr>');
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

```
 for (q = 0; q < 10; q++) { 
     var select = document.getElementById(names[i]); //q should be i here...
```

In fact you don't need the loop at all:

```
var EachName= textFileData.split("\n");
var select = document.getElementById(names[i]);
for (var j = 0, len = EachName.length; j < len; j++) {
   var option = document.createElement('option');
   option.text = option.value = EachName[j];
   select.add(option, 0);
}
```

The problem is your adding the names to all selects every iteration of your outer loop the one with `i`.

Try this update:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  var names = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
  //window.alert(names[i])
  document.write('<tr>');
  document.write('<td>');
  document.write('Enter name '+ names[i]);
  document.write('</td>');
  document.write('<td>');
  document.write('<select name=' + i + ' id=' + names[i] + '></select>');     
  var textFile = "/names.txt";       
  var closure = function(counter, namesArray) {
     return function(textFileData) {
         var EachName= textFileData.split("\n");
         var select = document.getElementById("" + namesArray[counter]);
         for (var j = 0, len = EachName.length; j < len; j++) {
             var option = document.createElement('option');
             option.text = option.value = EachName[j];
             select.add(option, 0);
         }
     };
  }
  jQuery.get(textFile, closure(i, names));
  document.write('</td>');
  document.write('</tr>');
};
```

[I got the code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939206/4028085)

Comment: I had tried this originally, but for whatever reason, the lists are not populated if I remove the loop. That just doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: @Drew an easy workaround would be to leave the loop but only do 1 iteration.  I'll edit my answer to show...

Comment: @Drew there I updated the answer also you don't need `;` at the end of your loops...

Comment: thanks for your help. If I try to add `i` where the `q` is, then I get the same error 10 times: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null`. But how can it be null if its defined above?

Comment: @Drew just check your `EachName` variable using `console.log(EachName)`

Comment: @Drew I think you are trying to access an element via the dom before it's been added.  Instead of adding options via dom manipulation add the options the same way you are adding the selects html direct injection...

Comment: @Drew there i updated my answer to create the options using html injection.

Comment: @Drew another problem is that `jQuery.get` is an asynchronous call

Comment: @brso05, thank you for all your help. Unfortunately, the lists are still not populated. I found that as soon as I enter the jQuery loop, the original `i` becomes undefined. Can I pass it in somehow?

Comment: @Drew I updated my answer using a closure check it out see if it works for you...

Comment: @brso05, I just got it, check below. All that was needed was to end the `i` loop after 10 iterations and then start the jQuery

Comment: @Drew if you want to try my answer with the closure it would save you from looping twice but if not it shouldn't be much overhead either way.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few things going on here that are causing you problems: You're q loop is running after only 1 iteration (and every iteration thereafter) of the i looop that contains it, so it's trying to select elements that haven't yet been created as well as selecting the first one 10 times in total :( Also declare names outside the loop as  theres no reason to declare it 10 times.

I don't have your textFile so I created a fake array with some names in it to create a similar effect for a version I made quickly. [edit] substituted your jQuery bit back in where I previously used an array for demonstration purposes.

```
var names = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  //window.alert(names[i])
  document.write('<tr>');
  document.write('<td>');
  document.write('Enter name '+ names[i]);
  document.write('</td>');
  document.write('<td>');
  document.write('<select name=' + i + ' id=' + names[i] + '></select>');
  document.write('</td>');
  document.write('</tr>');
}
var eachName;
jQuery.get(textFile, function(textFileData) { 
  eachName = textFileData.split("\n");
});
for (q = 0; q < 10; q++) {
  var select = document.getElementById(names[q]);
  for (var j = 0; j < eachName.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = option.value = eachName[j];
    select.add(option, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but unfortunately, the list has about 500 different names so it would probably be best to keep it in a text file

Comment: Thats fine swap out my declaration of an array for your bit of jQuery. I'll edit the post so it should work.

Comment: It was also a bad idea to include your bit of jQuery in one of the loops as it ran 10 times when it only needed to be done once.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working. I needed to break out of the first for loop and then go through and then add the names to the list

```
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                var names = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
                document.write('<tr>');
                document.write('<td>');
                document.write('Enter name '+ names[i]);
                document.write('</td>');
                document.write('<td>');
                document.write('<select name=' + i + ' id=' + names[i] + '></select>'); 
                document.write('</td>');
                document.write('</tr>');    
            };

            var textFile = "/names.txt";       
            jQuery.get(textFile, function(textFileData) { 
                var EachName= textFileData.split("\n"); 
                for (q = 0; q < 10; q++){ 
                    var select = document.getElementById(names[q]);
                    for (var j = 0, len = EachName.length; j < len; j++) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = option.value = EachName[j];
                        select.add(option, 0);
                 };
                     };
             });
```