# How to pass arguments to function using unobtrusive JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

In traditional code I will pass arguments to link button like this:

```
<a href="javascript:call_hello(1, 2, 3)" role="button">Hello</a>
```

How can I do it in unobtrusive JavaScript style with JQuery or similar library.

```
<a href="#" class="hello" arg1="1" arg2="2" arg3="3" role="button">Hello</a>
```

Do not focus that code is longer since it is only example. I want attach Javascript code in such way.

```
$(".hello").on('click', call_hello2);
```

Can you suggest the best solution in your opinion for unobtrusive JavaScript style (attaching Javascript by matching elements not by html code).

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass more parameters into callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/939032/1048572)

Comment: What are those args? Where are they coming from, should they really go into the HTML markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes which can be stored and fetched using [`$.fn.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Alternatively [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) can also be used.

> The `HTMLElement.dataset` read-only property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element. It is a map of DOMString, one entry for each custom data attribute.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var arg1 = $(this).data('arg1');
    
    alert(arg1)
    
    //Using native JS
    console.log(this.dataset.arg1)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="hello" data-arg1="1" data-arg2="2" data-arg3="3" role="button">Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The common approach for arguments passing to a jQuery plugin/helper in an unobtrusive way is to use the `data-*` attributes:

```
<a href="#" class="hello" data-arg1="1" data-arg2="2" data-arg3="3" role="button">Hello</a>
```

Then in your code:

```
$('.hello').on('click', function(e) {
    var options = $(this).data();

    if (options.arg1 == 1)
        ...
});
```

You can also set your default `options` and only override the passed arguments:

```
$('.hello').on('click', function(e) {
    var defaultOptions = {
         arg1: "something",
         arg2: "something2",
         arg3: "something3"
    },
    passedOptions = $(this).data(),
    options = $.extend(defaultOptions, passedOptions);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<a id="hello-button" href="#" class="hello" data-args="1,2,3" role="button">Hello</a>
```

with the following JavaScript:

```
function call_hello2() {
    var args = $("#hello-button").data('args').split(',');
    call_hello.apply(this, args);
}
```

This way you could have a variable number of arguments.

Finally, just use the code you posted:

```
$(".hello").on('click', call_hello2);
```

Comment: You are probably going to want to do `call_hello.apply(this, args)`  which will call the method like `(1,2,3)` vs `call_hello(args)` which is like `([1,2,3])`

Comment: @pllee nice point, would be more elegant. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
<a id="hello-button" href="#" class="hello" data-args="1,2,3" role="button">Hello</a>

$(".hello").on('click', function (e) {
    var el = $(e.target);
    var args = el.data('args').split(',');
    call_hello(args);
});
```

This is the most unobtrusive way of doing it. You don't clobber the DOM with lots of attributes nor create arbitrary JavaScript functions.