# jquery function running without being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

My basic setup is this:

```
function overLink ( e ){
    alert( e );
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#id" ).mouseover( overLink( this ) );
});
```

However 'overLink' is being called on page load, not when '#id' is hovered. I read that this is because of () in my function declaration, but I can't remove this as I want to pass a selector to the function. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery pass more parameters into callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing, when you "pass" `this` to the function like you are doing is to actually call the function. Try this instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id").mouseover(function() {
      overLink(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

its because you are calling the function and returning the result of it ti the mouseover listener .... 
you should instead pass the function reference ... not its result

```
   $( "#id" ).mouseover(overLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is right way of calling function :-

```
function overLink (e){
    alert(e);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#id" ).mouseover(function() {
     overLink( this );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When a function name is followed by parentheses (`()`), it is immediately invoked (executed) by JavaScript. To pass it as reference, omit the parens. This will work :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id").mouseover(overLink);
});
```

But since you are passing an argument to `overLink`, you should use an anonymous function :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id").mouseover(function(){
    overLink(this);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass `this` as an argument as `this` within `overLink` will be the element anyway.

```
function overLink(){
    alert(this);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id").mouseover(overLink);
});
```

Comment: You have a typo, `overlik` should be `overlink` at line 5 of your code.