# How do I loop over JQuery without causing a messing up the order in which my functions are run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a web scraper to get some specific information from some web pages. I have the links of the pages on a table and I want to create a loop so that in every iteration my function can load the html of a particular website and check if a phrase is located in that site. In the case where the phrase doesn't exist that table row will be deleted.

I realized that for some reason when I am running the loop, the JQuery function that should scrape an individual link waits for the loop to be over and then scrapes the same page 50 times, instead of scraping a different web page each time.

```js
    //snippet has been simplified to make the problem clear
    //assume urlList is a list of 50 different url's 

    function dataScraper(urlList){  
      for(i in urlList){
        $.get('https://allorigins.me/get?method=raw&url=' + encodeURIComponent(urlList[i]) + '&callback=?', function(data){
          localStorage.setItem("urlHTML"+String(i),data.contents)
          console.log(i) //for example this just prints 49, 50 times instead of printing all the separate values of i
          });
        }
       }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I get that JQuery is waiting for the whole thing to load, but how do I make sure that the JQuery function accepts each individual (i) instead of the max (i).

Disclaimer: I am a self-taught newbie, and have recently figured out JavaScript, HTML and JQuery. Apologies if I am missing something completely obvious.

Comment: If this is javascript, maybe you want to try reworking it to use "forEach()" and a counter instead? Something like  var i = 0; urlList.forEach(function(url) {  // all your get stuff ; i++; }); ?

Comment: `i` is not within the scope of your callback functions, so it just outputs the global value from the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery pass more parameters into callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback)

Comment: Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/x0g5m11x/) based on the referenced accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I reworked it based on comments provided and some more research.

```js
function dataScraper(urlList){
  var i = 0

  $.each(urlList,function(){
    $.get('https://allorigins.me/get?method=raw&url=' + encodeURIComponent(urlList[i]) + '&callback=?', function(data){
    localStorage.setItem("urlHTML"+String(i),data.contents)
    console.log(i)
    i++
        });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```